# Use of Scheduler in Web API usung C#

Tags: c#, mysql, scheduled-tasks

I want use scheduler to achieve following case:

Suppose I have ten user in my database and for all these user I have new table with UserId as foreign key. Lets say **UserId,Column1,Column2,CurrentYear** are the columns of table. Now as year changes on 31st Dec.(24:00:00) I need to add all existing user again in above table with CurrentYear=newYear and Column1 and Column2 with zero value every year. So that I can consider all refreshed values for every user in new year. Older value will be there just for record maintainance. I am completely new here. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what did you try before ? You can write some scheduled event on database level. See [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) for example. Or you can write Windows service which will be triggered once per year and do everything what you need

Comment: No Sir. As I told you, I am going to work on it first time. And I have some time limitation so I directly come here to get quick solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions to your problem is working directly with you database using [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

You create an event that starts on the first day of the next year and reoccurs every year. When it's fired, it reads all records from the table and inserts them back with updated values. Supposing that your table is called `"users"` it would look like something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT update_users
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
STARTS '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
DO 
    INSERT INTO users (UserId, CurrentYear)
    SELECT UserId, YEAR(CURDATE())
    FROM users
    WHERE CurrentYear = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1
```

Comment: OK Let me Check Sir. Thanks.

Comment: Sir I need to insert values in more two columns whose datatype is float. I can not repeat these values in my new insertion. I want zero in both columns.

Comment: INSERT INTO users (UserId, Column1, Column2, Year) : I think, if I am setting both column default value 0. Then no need to do something in our event to make it zero. right?

Comment: Yes, correct. If your columns have a default value they can be ignored in your INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

You will need continuously running jobs to achieve. I presume you are looking for a automated solution which updates the table every year at a particular date time.

There are several job schedulers available. Have a windows service that make use of scheduler. You could take a look at Quartz.NET which offers rich set of APIs to achieve your requirement.Below is the sample to have a trigger on Dec 31st:

```
           // Define your job
            IJobDetail yearlyJob = JobBuilder.Create<YourJobClass>()
                .WithIdentity("yearly", "group1")
                .Build();
            // Trigger the job to run 31st Dec 11.59.59 every 12 months
            ITrigger trigger_tcs = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("Run Infinitely every 2nd day of the month", "Monthly_Day_2")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("59 59 23 31 12 ? * "))
                .Build();
```